# Select * from Tabela e Não Select * from EntityName - JPA JAVA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

A minha query foi construida assim, porém quando ele faz a requisição:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CT.id FROM CursoTurno AS CT 
                LEFT JOIN Curso AS C ON C.id = CT.curso_id 
                INNER JOIN Turno AS T ON T.id = CT.turno_id 
                WHERE C.id = :curso AND T.id = :turno",
                nativeQuery = true)

public CursoTurno findByCursoeTurno(@Param("curso") long curso, @Param("turno") long turno);
```

Resulta nesse erro

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
>   "cursoturno" does not exist

Entity de Curso

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "cursoTurnos", "unidade" })
@Table(name = "curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "curso", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<CursoTurno> cursoTurnos;
```

Entity de Turno

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turno")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "horarios","cursoTurnos" })
public class Turno implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "turno")
    private List<CursoTurno> cursoTurnos;
```

Entity de CursoTurno

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "curso_turno")
public class CursoTurno implements Serializable {
  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "curso_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Curso curso;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "turno_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Turno turno;
```

Ele esta pegando o nome da entity e nao o nome da tabela.
Pesquisei como arrumar isso ai e nao achei nada convincente.

Comment: Você está usando Spring Data? (Se sim mencione na questão).
Remova o `nativeQuery = true` se sua intenção é usar JPQL. Veja também que em JPQL você não precisa especificar os IDs manualmente nos *joins*, e.g., `FROM CursoTurno AS CT LEFT JOIN Curso AS C ON C.id = CT.curso_id ` vira `FROM CursoTurno ct LEFT JOIN ct.curso c`.

Comment: Finalmente: A tabela de relacionamento `curso_turno` possui atributos além de `curso_id` e `turno_id`? Se não eu eliminaria a entidade `CursoTurno` e usaria um relacionamento [`@ManyToMany`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Example_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship_annotation).

Comment: Resultamos em 'SELECT ct FROM CursoTurno ct WHERE ct.curso.id = :idCurso AND ct.turno.id = :idTurno' deu certo , simples navalhada de novato .... De qqr forma valeuzao ai Anthony pelo help.